# Where can I find binarycreator in QT sdk for creating Qt Installer

Tags: linux, macos, qt, qt-installer

I am creating `Qt Installer` for some QT application, When I gone through the [Qt Installer Framework Manual](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qtifw-1.2/index.html) at [some point](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qtifw-1.2/ifw-tools.html#binarycreator) I found to rum `binarycreator` please see the image [image: below image] , but I am unable to find that binary file in `Qt SDK`, Please can any one help for this.

Answer (score 6):

You can either build the Qt Installer Framework yourself following instructions from [here](http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-getting-started.html), or download pre-built binaries for it from [the official releases page](https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt-installer-framework/), as specified in [this](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt-Installer-Framework) wiki page.

Once installed or built, `binarycreator` is found in the 'bin' directory, e.g. `E:\QtIFW2.0.1\bin`.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that <location-of-**ifw**> means the Location of the **I**nstaller **F**rame**w**ork, so that binary file must be part of the Installer Framework rather than the Qt SDK

Comment: Thanks for your interest @Tim Meyer, Can you tell me where could be that  Installer Framework folder

Comment: There is a "tools/binarycreator" folder in the source code of the QT Installer Framework (which you probably got from http://qt.gitorious.org/installer-framework). Maybe you need to build that executable yourself